# how to display all records using bookshelfjs

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

Why this is not displaying all channels. How can I display all channels.

```
new channelModel()
    .fetch()
    .then(function (channel) {
        console.log(channel.attributes.name);
        if (channel) {
            res.json({error: false, status: 200, data: channel.attributes.name});
        } else {
            res.json({error: true, status: 404, data: 'channel does not exist'});
        }
    })
    .otherwise(function (err) {
        res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
    });
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fetchAll`:

```
new channelModel()
   .fetchAll()
   .then(function (channels) {
       channels.forEach(function(channel) {
          // do something with each channel
       });
       // or just respond with JSON array assuming this is an Express app:
       res.send(channels.toJSON());
   })
```

I haven't actually tried the `forEach` function, but [according to bookshelf.js documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) it should work. If you're doing a REST service, you probably want to just serialize the collection (array) as JSON.